# Simple Callback with MASShortcut using Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoapods

I installed the latest (2015-02-03) MASShortcut as CocoaPod together with a correct bridging header for a very basic OS X Swift Application. I ended up with the following code and I do not know what I am doing wrong?:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func callback() {
         NSLog("callback")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let keyMask = NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask | NSEventModifierFlags.AlternateKeyMask
        let shortcut = MASShortcut.shortcutWithKeyCode(kVK_Space, modifierFlags: UInt(keyMask.rawValue))
        MASShortcut.addGlobalHotkeyMonitorWithShortcut(shortcut, handler: callback)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Before fixing them you should make sure that you have `MASShortcut` 2.1.2 installed (you can see this in your `Podfile.lock`). If you don't you should run `pod update` to get the newest version.

Another potential issue with you testing this is your shortcut conflicting with OS X default shortcuts. In your current example <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is bound to opening a Finder window and selecting the search field. If you have this disabled that's fine, otherwise I would recommend adding <kbd>Control</kbd> to your test case.

So there are a few issues with your code so far. First off I would recommend changing your `keyMask` declaration a bit to:

```
let keyMask: NSEventModifierFlags = .CommandKeyMask | .ControlKeyMask | .AlternateKeyMask
```

This way Swift can infer the type and you only have to have `NSEventModifierFlags` once (notice that I added the `.ControlKeyMask` here for my comment above).

A cool part about enums in Swift is that you can call `rawValue` on them. In this case the `rawValue` of `NSEventModifierFlags` is a `UInt` which will fix your type problem when creating your shortcut.

Now your `keyCode` argument must be a `UInt` as well. So you can pull this out into a temporary value:

```
let keyCode = UInt(kVK_Space)
```

In Swift, methods that look like class level initializers are actually turned in to Swift initializers. So in this case, you're trying to call a class method called `shortcutWithKeyCode:modifierFlags:` when Swift has actually turned this into an initializer. So you can create your shortcut like this:

```
let shortcut = MASShortcut(keyCode: keyCode, modifierFlags: keyMask.rawValue)
```

Note the `rawValue` call to convert our modifier flags into a `UInt`.

Finally, the API to register this shortcut globally is actually a method on `MASShortcutMonitor`. In your bridging header where you have:

```
#import <MASShortcut/MASShortcut.h>
```

You'll have to add a new import to get this API. The new one is:

```
#import <MASShortcut/MASShortcutMonitor.h>
```

Now you can register your shortcut:

```
MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().registerShortcut(shortcut, withAction: callback)
```

And your all set. Your callback function was already setup correctly!

One last thing. I would recommend removing your shortcut in `applicationWillTerminate:` like this:

```
MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().unregisterAllShortcuts()
```

Answer (score -1):

Wow, that is a great answer. Thank you so much! I realized that I should have studied the basics of Swift a little bit longer. Your solution works perfectly!

However, one little detail is superfluous. You do not have to add the bridging header

```
#import <MASShortcut/MASShortcutMonitor.h>
```

if you create the bridging header file like it is shown in the documentation. My bridging header file contains

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <MASShortcut/Shortcut.h>
```

and Shortcut.h already refers to the MASShortcutMonitor.h.

Again: Thanks a lot!!